# Jquery, Pass Input Data to an Array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a set of array on the text field

```
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
```

How to can I prevent passing duplicate array

this is my jquery code

```
  $(document).on("click", ".open_modal", function() {

  //var values = $('input[name^="owner"]').map((i, a) => a.value).get();
  var values = $('input[name="owner[]"]').val();


  if(values == values) {
    alert('exist');  /* how to validate duplicate array */
  }
  $("#owner_value").val(values);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Array.filter()` to filter duplicate values, `values.filter((a, b) => values.indexOf(a) === b);`

Before that we need to push all the values to an array. This is what I did

```
var values = [];
    $('input[name="owner[]"]').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
```

```js
var $ = jQuery;
 $(document).on("click", ".open_modal", function() {
var values = [];
var owners = ['john', 'wons', 'kolins'];
$('input[name="owner[]"]').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
values = [...values, ...owners]; // here we merge both arrays and then remove the duplicates. 
  if(values.length) {
  values = values.filter((a, b) => values.indexOf(a) === b);
   // console.log(values); // now duplicates are removed.    
  }
  var htmlContent='';
  values.forEach((user)=>{
    if(user){
    htmlContent +=`<p>${user}</p></br>`;
    }
  })
  
  $("#owner_value").html(htmlContent);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Reys">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">

<p> Test btn </p>
<button class="open_modal">Open Modal </button>

<div id="owner_value"></div>
```

Comment: this works. how can i use `.join('<br>')` because I am trying to join the 2 array into a `p tag` to my modal  `$("#owner_html").val(values);` 

this is my `<p id="owner_html"></p>`

Comment: So you are trying to join `array 1` and `array 2`, like `[jon, won, don]` and `[ roy, joy, coy]`, then display those in a `p` tag, eg. `<p> jon </p> <p> won </p> ...`, like., right ?

Comment: yes done thank you. can i ask ``<p>${user}</p></br>`` what is this  (`) why cant i use a (")

Comment: Its template literal, you can refer the doc and you will get good info from there rather than me explaining. :). I am bad in explaining bro, sorry. Please check the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

using reduce can prevent repeat value:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const $values = $('input[name^="owner"]').map((i, a) => a.value).get()

  const $filterValues = $values.reduce((acc, item) => (!acc.includes(item) && acc.push(item), acc), [])
  console.log($filterValues)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
```

Answer (score 0):

Index of all items in an array with the index of the first occurrence of the same item, If indexes are not the same returns it as duplicate.

```js
function getUnique(array){
    var uniqueArray = [];
    for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(uniqueArray.indexOf(array[i]) === -1) {
            uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueArray;
}

var names = ["John", "Peter", "Clark", "Harry", "John", "Alice"];
var uniqueNames = getUnique(names);
console.log(uniqueNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mix of map and includes like below:

```
var existingValues = [];
  var values = $('input[name^="owner"]').map((i, a) => {
    if (!existingValues.includes(a.value)) {
      existingValues.push(a.value);
      console.log(a.value);
      return a;
    }
  });
```

```js
function getUnique() {
  var existingValues = [];
  var values = $('input[name^="owner"]').map((i, a) => {
    if (!existingValues.includes(a.value)) {
      existingValues.push(a.value);
      console.log(a.value);
      return a;
    }
  });
  console.log(values.length);
  console.log(values);
}

getUnique();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run below code it will remove duplicate records

```
  var myArray = ["Hardik", "Rajesh", "Sagar", "Hardik", "Sanju"];

  var myNewArray = myArray.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
      return index === self.indexOf(elem);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`$.unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

```js
var values = $.unique($('input[name="owner[]"]').map((i, el) => el.value).get())

console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement the solution: I have included few of them

## HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
```

## Naive solution:

```
(function($){
  $(document).on("click", ".submit", function() {
    var values = $('input[name="owner[]"]');
    var stores = [];
    values.each(function(index, value){
      stores.push($(this).val());
    });
    for(var i = 0; i <= stores.length; i++) {
        for(var j = i; j <= stores.length; j++) {
            if(i != j && stores[i] == stores[j]) {
                console.log('Duplicates exists!');
            }
        }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The above code implements two nested loops to find duplicates!

## Naive approach with slightly better performance:

```
(function($){
  $(document).on("click", ".submit", function() {
    var values = $('input[name="owner[]"]');
    var stores = [];
    values.each(function(index, value){
      stores.push($(this).val());
    });
    var counts = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <= stores.length; i++) {
        if(counts[stores[i]] === undefined) {
            counts[stores[i]] = 1;
        } else {
            console.log('Duplicate exsist!');
        }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

behind the process this approach is followed in most of the standard libraries or existing functions with some additional performance improvements.

## Here is another way of doing the same using some existing helper functions:

```
(function($){
  $(document).on("click", ".submit", function() {
    var values = $('input[name="owner[]"]');
    var stores = [];
    values.each(function(index, value) {
        console.log($(this).val());
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), stores) == -1){
          console.log('No Duplicate');
          stores.push($(this).val());
        }else{
          console.log('Duplicate Exist');
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```